# x64 fasm strlen

Tags: strings, assembly, x86

This is a simple strlen function with registers documented:

```
;in rdi - string to measure
;out rax - len
.my_strlen:
test rdi, rdi
jz ptr_error
or rcx, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
mov al, 0
cld
repne scasb
mov rax, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
sub rax, rcx
ret
```

NOTE: This code assumes a "C-Style string"; that is, a NUL-terminated string.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> or rcx, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
> ```

This is an optimization for size, but it does not break the dependency on the old value of `rcx` (at least not yet, maybe someday, it's not an impossible feature). That's a minor point compared to overall cost of a `strlen` but it's something to know so you can make the choice deliberately.

> ```
> cld
> ```

Should be redundant, typical calling conventions specify that the direction flag is cleared at function call boundaries so your `strlen` shouldn't be called with it set to backwards.

> ```
> mov rax, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
> sub rax, rcx
> ```

mov-ing a 64bit immediate is surprisingly slow, and also a huge instruction. An alternative is:

```
not rcx
mov rax, rcx
```